# How to change randomised data used for graph values with my input data? D3js donut graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am fairly new to coding and I need to use d3js library to make graphs. While I get the basics, I don't yet comprehend the whole thing...

So, I found this graph in D3js examples that i want to use. but don't know how to change data showing in graph. I want donut chart to have my input data instead of randomised data as it is shown in example

http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799
This is a graph I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

the key function is `change()`, just replace randomData() to getYourData()

```
function getYourData() {
  let yourData = [
    {
      label: 'label1',
      value: 12,
    },
    {
      label: 'label2',
      value: 6,
    }
  ]

  return yourData;
}

change(getYourData());
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't actually don't need to change data (don't need that randomize button to change data), so just graph that looks like that with my input data

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can understand this syntax more easily

```
change([ { label: "Label 1", value: 10 }, 
         { label: "Label 2", value: 20 },
         { label: "Label 3", value: 30 } ])
```

The function *change* takes an **array** of **objects**, each **object** is a segment of the pie graph.